# Data from SPSS Model into my website

Tags: python, spss

I'm researching a good way to get my SPSS model logic into my website in real time. Currently we built a shody python script that mimics what the SPSS model does with the data. The problem is whenever we make an update or optimization to the SPSS model we have to go in and adjust the python code. How do people solve for this usually?

I've gotten a suggestion to create a config file for all the frequently updated functions in SPSS to translate over to the current python script. We're open to completely generating the python script from the SPSS model though, if there's a way to do that.

I've looked into cursor method but these seem have their main value in automating SPSS with python, which isn't really what we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the use of the Watson Machine Learning service on IBM Bluemix.

https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/machine-learning?taxonomyNavigation=data

The SPSS Streams Service that is part of this allows you to take your stream, deploy it, and then call it via REST API.

Note the Streams Service does not support legacy R nodes, Extension nodes (R or Python code), or Predictive Extensions. However, it does support Text Analytics.

The service allows up to 5000 calls a month for free and then can be purchased on a per prediction basis.

Comment: Thank you so much. What exactly does Text Analytics mean?

Comment: SPSS Modeler Premium has a text analytics component as well. It will read in text and based on custom and libraries already included will look to extract concepts and meaning from that text. Ultimately the idea is to create new features (columns) that represent these concepts so that they can then be included in a model. The ability to score text analytics is also included in the SPSS Streams service on Bluemix.